# Normalising Model Parameters

Tags: time-series, anova, normalization

I have several sets of data-points, each representing the growth of a cell population through time under different therapeutic strengths plus a control one. I have fit a polynomial function to each of them using polynomial regression, and now have one function per set.

In order to determine whether the treatments affect the rates of growth, I have used One-Way ANOVA where inputs are the coefficients of the function's equation. Results give p=0.41, which is clearly not significant.

However, by looking at my graph there does seem to be a difference between Level VI and Control, especially for higher values of time.

[image]

Rates of growth are also considerably higher for Level VI than control:

[image]

So I went ahead and normalised my coefficients before using one-way ANOVA again, which returns p=0.09, which suggests I suppose a possibility of rejecting the null hypothesis for p=0.1? However, I'm unsure whether this procedure is correct/if it makes any sense to normalise my parameters?

Comment: It is difficult to see the source of errors in the above plot. Take for example the control group (red line). Is there multiple participants in that group? If such is the case, could you add error bars (e.g. 95% confidence intervals) around each point? The polynomial, was it fit for each participant separately or is it one polynomial for the group? In that case, how can you assess the standard error of the estimated parameters? Without standard error, it is impossible to make any kind of statistical test. Thank you to provide additional information.